# Help to understand a sentence from a Page Six news article

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> Nordstrom parted ways with the brand, which was launched in 2014, as far back as February 2017, citing “brand performance.”

As I understand the sentence, it means Nordstrom went with the brand from 2014(launched date) to February 2017. Am I getting it right? What about *citing "brand performance."*?

Also, the sentence structure looks odd to me. I don't know how to parse it correctly.

Here is the [full source](https://pagesix.com/2018/07/24/ivanka-trumps-fashion-company-is-shutting-down/?utm_campaign=iosapp&utm_source=pasteboard_app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is “information dense”; it is using very few words to convey a great deal of information.

Your interpretation is partially correct; Nordstrom was ‘going with’ Ms Trump’s brand (that is, Nordstrom stores were selling merchandise from the company) prior to February, 2017 - though the article doesn’t indicate whether it started to do so in 2014 or later. It apparently ceased to do so at that time, and *citing “brand performance”* indicates that Nordstrom gave as the reason for no longer selling the brand that they were not selling sufficient merchandise to make it worthwhile to continue to do so.

Summary of that sentence:

- Ms Trump’s brand was created in 2014.
- Nordstrom was selling merchandise branded with Ms Trump’s brand, but we don’t know when they started to do so.
- Nordstrom stopped selling merchandise branded with Ms Trump’s brand in February of 2017.
- Nordstrom said that they were not selling enough of Ms Trump’s merchandise to make it worthwhile for them to continue to do so, and this is why they stopped.

Comment: So, *citing brand performance* implies brand performance is bad? Can you help to spell it out a bit? Thanks!

Comment: _citing brand performance_ **as a reason for no longer selling a brand** almost invariably means that the brand performance is inadequate. A company can also _cite brand performance_ as a reason for expanding the amount and styles of the brand carried; in such a case, it would mean that they were selling so much of it that it would be worthwhile to carry even more, to meet the demand for it.

Comment: Excellent breakdown of the timeline